# Proof that if p, q , and r are three different prime numbers, then p^2+q^2 ≠ r^2

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone prove this? Any advice on how to deal with proofs that involve prime numbers that don't have any relationship? In all the other proofs that I've worked on, they are usually successive or they divide something in common, etc. But in this one, I can't see any relationship or association that can help me solve the problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by saying that $p^2 = r^2 - q^2 = (r - q)(r + q)$. This leaves you with very few options. Either the right hand side must be of the form $1 \cdot p^2$, or it has to be of the form $p \cdot p$. Split into cases, and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

Something you may notice is that one of $p$ and $q$ had better be $2$, otherwise $p^2 + q^2$ would be the sum of two odd squares, and thus be even. That would imply $2 \mid r^2$ and therefore $2 \mid r$, which is impossible unless $r = 2$ as $r$ is prime. It follows that $q^2 = r^2 - p^2 = 0$, a contradiction as $q = 0$ is not prime.

Without loss of generality, let $p = 2$, giving $4 = r^2 - q^2$. However, no two odd perfect squares differ by exactly 4 due to the following.

Letting $r = 2a + 1$ and $q = 2b + 1$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$, we have $$r^2 - q^2 = (2a + 1)^2 - (2b + 1)^2 = (2a - 2b)^2(2a + 2b + 2)^2 = 4$$ which forces $(a - b)(a + b + 1) = 1$, or $a - b = a + b + 1 = \pm 1$, which has no integer solutions in either case. By contradiction, $2^2 + q^2 = r^2$ has no solutions over the primes, so neither does the original equation.

Using parity in problems involving primes is occasionally useful since all except one are odd. In this case, it's pretty overkill; Theo's approach is faster and simpler. But it's something I personally check for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way through:

$r$ cannot be $2$, so must be odd.

At least one of $p$ and $q$ must be odd - say $p$.

$r^2-p^2=q^2$ and the difference of the squares of two odd integers (hence of two odd primes) is divisible by $8$. (Any odd square $\equiv 1 \bmod 8$). No square of a prime is divisible by $8$.

I'll leave you to fill in the details, which are well-known - it takes less discussion of cases than other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

All prime numbers are odd except $2$. Suppose $a, b, c$ are three odd prime numbers such that $c^2=a^2+b^2$. From Pythagorean theorem, $c\gt a$ and $c\gt b$. Thus, $a^2=c^2-b^2 \gt 0$. Suppose $c=2p+1$ and $b=2q+1$ where $p$ and $q$ are any integers such that $p \gt q$. Then:
$$a^2=c^2-b^2 =(c+b)(c-b)=(2p+1+2q+1)(2p+1-2q-1)=4(p+q+1)(p-q)$$ 
This means, $a^2=(2r)^2$ where $r=\sqrt{(p+q+1)}$, and therefore, $a$ is not a prime number.

Similarly, if $b=2$,
 $$a^2=c^2-b^2 =(c+b)(c-b)=(2p+1+2)(2p+1-2)=(2p+3)(2p-1)$$
Therefore, $a^2$ has two non-equal integer factors, and hence, $a$ cannot be a prime number.